# PHP cURL TLS 1.0 to 1.2

Tags: php, curl

I'm updating some old php code and noticed the API I'm interacting with requires TLS 1.1 or 1.2. Running the code below the returning result is

> TLS 1.0

How do I get PHP to use TLS 1.1 or 1.2? Another post I ca across mentioned setting CURLOPT_SSLVERSION but that didn't seem to do the trick on my end.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($data);
echo $json->tls_version;
```

Comment: What cURL version are you using? echo `curl_version()['version_number']` and tell us what you get

Comment: I am using version 463623

Comment: It seems you need a version of cURL that is greater than `467456` (`7.34`) to have TLS 1.1 or 1.2 enabled.